# Unable to read Files in SparkSQL in java

Tags: java, json, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please help, I'm a complete noob when it comes to Spark and Haddop in general. My code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] jars = {"D:\\customJars\\sparky.jar","D:\\customJars\\guava-19.0.jar"};
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("com.nucleus.spark.MlibPOC")
                .setMaster("spark://10.1.50.165:7077")
                .setJars(jars);


    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);


   DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("src/com/nucleus/spark/generated.json");


}
```

My Spark Cluster is deployed as a single cluster at 10.1.50.165 running RHEL6 and when I run this simple code, while trying to read the json file I get exceptions like:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 10.1.50.165):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/D:/WorkSpace2/SparkHadoopProject/src/com/nucleus/spark/generated.json
>   does not exist    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1025)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1007)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1127)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.InferSchema$.infer(InferSchema.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:109)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema$lzycompute(JSONRelation.scala:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema(JSONRelation.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:636)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:635)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:244)
>     at com.nucleus.spark.MlibPOC.main(MlibPOC.java:44) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/D:/WorkSpace2/SparkHadoopProject/src/com/nucleus/spark/generated.json
>   does not exist    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: The `FileNotFoundException` is the clue here... it can't find `D:/WorkSpace2/SparkHadoopProject/src/com/nucleus/spark/generated.json`.

Comment: Yes, but the file is there at        "D:/WorkSpace2/SparkHadoopProject/src/com/nucleus/spark/generated.json" I've put it there & checked it over and over again

Comment: Perhaps try setting it explicitly to: `D:\\WorkSpace2\\SparkHadoopProject\\src\\com\\nucleus\\spark\\generated.json`

Comment: It still gives me the exact same exception! :(

Comment: Well, there is definitely a problem with the path - try to move the file to the root and see if it will read it from there.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, didn't work, I even tried moving the file to my server 10.1.50.165 and reading it from there....... same issue
Though I tried reading from hdfs on 10.1.50.165 like this:
  `DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("hdfs://10.1.50.165/sample.json");`

it then says: No input paths specified in job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on Spark 1.6:

```
    scala> val jtex = sqlContext.read.json("file:///opt/test.json")
    jtex: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string, age: string, id: string, name: string]

    scala> val jtex = sqlContext.read.format("json").option("samplingRatio", "1.0").load("file:///opt/test.json")
    jtex: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: string, id: string, name: string]

    scala> jtex.show()
    +---+----+-------+
    |age|  id|   name|
    +---+----+-------+
    | 25|1201| satish|
    | 28|1202|krishna|
    | 39|1203|  amith|
    | 23|1204|  javed|
    | 23|1205| prudvi|
    +---+----+-------+
```

Comment: Force path to go to local fs with file:///; in case of multicluster environment, this file has to be present on all machines.

Comment: Yes!! This is running in spark-shell on `10.1.50.165`,
`val jtex = sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/npdfinn/generated.json")`
 but how do i make this work in my java program which is on a different machine? Please help! The same path does not work there! 
`No input paths specified in job`

Comment: You have to run the spark app on the server and tune the required jars, files, etc. to point to that system. You can create the spark app on your local machine, but eventually you have to run it on the server, and move all required files and modify all pointers to that server.

Comment: So I can't run it from eclipse on my local machine?

Comment: yes, you can't run it from eclipse. You have to package it, send it to the server and run it via spark-submit.

Comment: Hello **AlexLorincz** you tried a single line json file or multiple ?